# Unity Vuforia Cloud iPhone 4

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, cloud, vuforia

I'm using Unity 4.5.1f3 with a pretty recently downloaded version of Vuforia 3.0.x

I'm having issues with getting cloud tracking working on an iPhone 4, while local tracking works. I have my app working correctly on an iPad 3, iPad 2, iPhone 5c, and a GalaxyS3, so I'm confused why the iPhone 4 would have cloud problems.

Thank you.